# Доработка по обязательному выбору value по условиям в Select

Tags: jquery

Необходимо доработать скрипт. Когда выбиралась type val=1   и cause кроме value 15  то нужно в обязательном порядке выбрать validId val 1 или 2.

JQery

```
if ($('#type').val()==1 && $('#validId').val() == 1 && $('#satisf').val() == '') {
$('.errorrep').append('<h3>Выберете поле Удовлетворена </h3>');
$('.errorrep').css({'display':'block'});
$('#draggable').animate({
scrollTop: 0
});
return false;
}
```

Мои примерные заметки для второго файла

```
if ($('#type').val()==1 && $('# cause').val() != 15 && $('# validId').val() == '') {
$('.errorrep').append('<h3>Выберете поле Обоснованно</h3>');
$('.errorrep').css({'display':'block'});
$('#draggable').animate({
scrollTop: 0
});
return false;
}
```

HTML

```
<select id="type" name="typeId" onchange="document.getElementById('typeWarning').hidden = true;">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="1">Жалоба</option>
<option value="2">Заявление</option>
<option value="3">Консультация</option>
<option value="4">Предложение</option></select>
…
<select id="cause" name="causeId" onchange="document.getElementById('causeWarning').hidden = true;">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="8">10 </option>
<option value="9">11 </option>
<option value="10">12 </option>
<option value="11">13 </option>
<option value="12">14 </option>
<option value="13">15 </option>
<option value="14">16 </option>
<option value="15">17 </option>
<option value="1">3 </option>
<option value="2">4 </option>
<option value="3">5 </option>
<option value="4">6 </option>
<option value="5">7 </option>
<option value="6">8 </option>
<option value="7">9 </option></select>
…
<select id="validId" name="validId">
<option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
   <option value="1">ДА</option>
<option value="2">НЕТ</option>
</select>
…
<select id="satisf" name="satisf" class="css-input">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="ДА">ДА</option>
<option value="НЕТ">НЕТ</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Приведите разметку, первый файл явно не под условия задачи написан.

Comment: Добавил html код

Comment: Да спасибо первый файл не под условие задачи, а второй получается только случит примером.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал в отдельном скрипте, дополнив условие, если кто знает как соединить два скрипта в один, т.е. который изначально в задании и который приведен ниже.

```
else if($('#type').val() == 1 && $('#cause').val() != 15 && $('#validId').val() != 1 && $('#validId').val() != 2){
    $('.errorrep').append('<h3>Поле "Обоснованность" обязательно для заполнения</h3>');
    $('.errorrep').css({'display':'block'});
    $('#draggable').animate({
        scrollTop:  0
    });
    return false;
}
```